# Monte carlo method and Convergence in Distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, monte-carlo, convergence

Monte Carlo method, from what I could gather, allows one to obtain observations/draws from a possibly unknown statistical distribution. Let's say $T(X)\sim F$, where $T$ is a statistic, $X$ is a random vector, and $F$ is possibly unknown distribution.

The method is composed of the following steps:

- Draw ${x_i}$ from a distribution $F_X$.
- Compute ${T(x_1)=t_1,..., T(x_m)=t_m}$. We have m samples, giving m values from the statistic.
- Use the set ${t_1,...,t_m}$ to compute histograms, quantiles, etc.

Well, I was trying to apply this to check the Central Limit Theorem. So, I followed the steps of the MC method, and draw an histogram

[image]

From one histogram to the other I increased the sample size.The $m$ is number of samples. In each histogram I used $m=20000$. By sample size $n$, I mean each sample has $n$ observations. For the histograms I used $n=10, 100, 1000$

It looks nice.

The problem is that the CLT is a result of convergence of distributions, and what I draw are an approximation to the density(histogram) and the limiting normal density. Having convergence of densities implies convergence of distributions, by Scheffé's theorem. However, we the converse is not generally true. We may have the same distribution, with several different densities. So, although what I did looked nice, it seems wrong.

Should I have, instead of an histogram of a density, tried to plot an 'histogram of the distribution'?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sounds like you are missing one asymptotic dimension: not only the sample size must grow to $\infty$ to recover the distribution of interest, but for a CLT the sample on which each term of the sample is computed must also grow to $\infty$...

Comment: @Xi'an. The $m$ is number of samples. In the histogram I used 20000. By sample size $n$, I mean each sample has $n$ observations. For the histograms I used $n=10, 100, 1000$

Comment: Then you are fine, producing a sample of independent $\bar{X}_n$ which limiting distribution is a $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Looking at the histogram sounds kosher to me...

Comment: @Xi'an but the thing is that the TLC is a result for convergence in distribution, while usually convergence of histograms is convergence of densities, which needs convergence in probability if I'm not mistaken. Either way, Shouldn't I have drawn an approximation to the CDF instead of an approximation to a PDF?

Comment: I do not understand, pdf and cdf are two faces of the same coin, i.e., they both characterise the probability distribution. Or are you worried about the histogram being a poor estimate of the density, when compared with the empirical cdf as an estimator of the cdf?

Comment: @Xi'an Since a cdf may have several pdf, I'm worried that the histogram may approximate one pdf that my not be the most used/natural one...  Unless that the only variability in the pdf of a continuous r.v. is through varying values of isolated points, in which case the histogram will not capture that.

Comment: You are correct that a rigorous treatment of convergence concerns the distribution function (cdf) rather than the density (which for general $F$ doesn't even exist).  What prevents you from drawing plots of the distribution functions?

Comment: @whuber I would like first to understand if it's really useful/necessary. I was wondering if the only case where the densities are different for the same distributions are for null measure sets, which would not be captured by the histograms... or if there are other types of sets, which in this case could be captured by the histogram.

Comment: Because the distribution function is the integral of the density, the integral of the difference of two densities would be everywhere zero.  That's equivalent to saying that the densities differ at most on a set of measure zero.